# Stable/unstable equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider:
>   $$
> \dfrac{dN}{dt} = -rN \left(1-\dfrac{N}{K_1}\right) \left(1- \dfrac{N}{K_2}\right),
> $$ 
>   where $r,K_1,K_2$ are constants s.t. $r>0 $ and $0 < K_1<K_2$. Find the the equilibrium points and determine if they are stable or unstable.

I have $ N = 0,K_1,K_2$ as the equilibrium solutions, and I'm trying to determine if they are stable, if they are then it shold be a local minimum, and if they are unstable it should be a local maximum.

So, for $ N < 0, K_1<N<K_2$ $\dfrac{dN}{dt} > 0 $ and for $ K_1>N > 0, N>K_2$ $\dfrac{dN}{dt} < 0 $ so for points around $N = 0$ we have the gradient increasing to the left ($N<0$) and the gradient decreasing for $0 < N < K_1$ so I assume that N = 0 is therefore a maximum point and an unstable equilibrium point. Similarly for $K_2$, and $K_1$ is a stable equilibrium point. However in the solutions they get $N=0,K_2$ is stable and $N=K_1$ unstable and they explain it by "solutions a bit bigger than them get smaller and solutions a bit smaller than them get bigger." - could someone explain where my analysis is wrong

Comment: I've copied the question exactly yes

Comment: I'm sorry but the author got a different answer to me (exact opposite). Is my analysis wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a direction field plot with a representative choice for your parameters.

Look at the direction, but also look at the magnitude of the slopes.

[image]

You just misinterpreted your correct analysis, so the author is correct.

We have that $0$ and $K_2$ are stable, but $K_1$ is unstable.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but which negative sign exactly? Where does my analysis go wrong?

Comment: No not exactly clear - my analysis was based on the gradient only (as I've never used phase portraits before). Considering each section ($N<0$, $0<N<K_1$, $N>K_2$, $K_1<N<K_2$) I believe I got the gradient correct, so I don't see why my conclusion is wrong... I definitely considered -r when figuring out the gradient.

Comment: Lets take $N = 0$, you have the correct direction for the gradient, but the incorrect conclusion. If I have a point and all trajectories are approaching it from below and above, it is stable. If I have a point where all trajectories or one is coming in and one leaving, those are unstable. SO, for $N=0, K_2$ are both approaching it from below and above, those are stable, but for $K_1$, they are both leaving it from above and from below, so that is unstable.

Comment: I see, but we defined in lecture stable points to be minimum points and unstable to be maximum. Surely at say $N = 0$ you have, from the left, the gradient positive, and from the right, the gradient negative so this concludes that $N=0$ is a local maximum no?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what the lecturer said. Your analysis makes sense - thank you for your help.

Comment: @Amzoti What software did you use to plot the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is correct. $N=0$ and $N=K_2$ are unstable equilibria, while $N=K_1$ is stable.

You could try packages in Mathematica or Matlab for phase pictures to further convince yourself.